LabTainer VM not starting on VirtualBox in Ubuntu 24.04 – Fix or alternatives?
I am an engineering student, and for a cybersecurity class, the professor assumes everyone uses Mac or Windows (I’m the only one on Ubuntu). He wants us to use a virtual machine called LabTainer, which runs on VirtualBox (.ova extension). Unfortunately, when I try to launch the VM, I get the error message
Result Code:
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)

Component:
MachineWrap

Interface:
IMachine {e36a5081-a82a-40bd-9e4e-42a44d6ce50f}

No log is created in the ~/VirtualBox VMs/LabtainerVM24 folder. After hours of searching, I can’t find a solution, and it’s frustrating because I’m losing time on the actual work. Do you know how to resolve this or if there’s an alternative to VirtualBox? I’m currently trying to convert the ova file to work with Virtual Machine Manager. I've already tried uninstalling using the command purge and remove and re-installing the latest VirtualBox version 7.1 from the official website, and I have latest Qt and SDL dependencies.
Thanks!
EDIT : I finally found a solution

Most likely you can find help on that on the VirtualBox  support site. That app also has its own support site. Do a Google search on Labtainer

Please post your solution in the answerbox below. It will greatly help future users

I finally found a solution on my own :
I extracted the myVM.ova file using the command tar -xvf myVM.ova to get myVM.vmdk
Then I converted the file myVM.vmdk with the command qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O qcow2 myVM.vmdk myVM.qcow2, it is necessary to wait few minutes for the command to be executed
Then optional :
I moved the file myVM.qcow2 to the folder /var/lib/libvirt/images/
I created a virtual machine on Virtual Machine Manager and it works ! A real relief after more than 6 hours of struggle
